# Ошибка Qt Platform после компиляции приложения

Tags: c++, qt

При запуске приложения на другом ПК, вылетает ошибка на скриншоте[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDUf4.jpg)

Подскажите в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данная ошибка возникает в связи с тем, что приложение не может найти плагин для платформы "windows". Чтобы приложение нормально работало, в том каталоге, где расположен бинарный файл приложения, необходимо создать каталог `platforms` и скопировать туда файл `qwindows.dll`, который можно найти в подкаталоге `plugins` каталога установки `Qt`.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогло!